# Can anybody point me to a link that describes what the url (dots) mean for example?

Tags: css, hyperlink

what does `./CoverFlows_files/coverflow.js` mean?

I understand `../CoverFlows_files/coverflow.js` means [move up one directory]
And `/CoverFlows_files/coverflow.js` means [go down from here]

Also is there are way to get to the root like in asp.net its `~/` ...?

The other thing I dont quite understand is where to put

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CoverFlows_files/coverflow.css">
```

and

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="./CoverFlows_files/coverflow.js"></SCRIPT>
```

Do these two tags have to go in the head or in the body or does it not matter?

I suppose if anybody has a link to a webpage that goes over these basic topics that would be immensly useful.

Regards
PQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paths aren't used only in "web-environments" so I'll try to explain it a but further.
(I'll use following syntax: `where we are` + `what path we type` = `what's the absolute path`)

- `./path/to/file` search only in current dictionary:

  - `/home/crozin` + `./path/to/file` = `/home/crozin/path/to/file`
  - `http://blah.com/support/` + `./path/to/file` = `http://blah.com/support/path/to/file`
- `/path/to/file` is absolute path:

  - `/home/crozin` + `/path/to/file` = `/path/to/file`
  - `http://blah.com/support/` + `/path/to/file` = `http://blah.com/path/to/file`
- `path/to/file` search in every directory from `include_path` (OS variable). So if `include_path` is set to: `.;/home/crozin;/tmp` then it'll search in:

  - `/home/crozin` + `path/to/file` = `./path/to/file` and `/home/crozin/path/to/file` and `/tmp/path/to/file`
  - `http://blah.com/support/` + `path/to/file` = `http://blah.com/support/path/to/file` (basically the same as first example)

In `...: url(...)` always use absolute path. In "web-environments" it's easiest style.

Answer (score 4):

`./` mean current directory

`CoverFlows_files/coverflow.css` and `./CoverFlows_files/coverflow.css` are basically same

`/CoverFlows_files/coverflow.css` is absolute path from domain name

For Example `http://yoursite.com/CoverFlows_files/coverflow.css` same as `/CoverFlows_files/coverflow.css`

Regarding stylesheets and scripts, you could put it anywhere

But good practice to speed up your web site is

[Put Stylesheets at the Top](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#css_top)

[Put Scripts at the Bottom](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)